# for-loop, increment by double

Tags: java, for-loop, double

I want to use the for loop for my problem, not while. Is it possible to do the following?:

```
for(double i = 0; i < 10.0; i+0.25)
```

I want to add double values.

Comment: Just keep in mind that due to rounding errors (misnomer I know) you most likely won't end on a nice round number.

Comment: It so happens that all the values taken by `i` in your program are representable exactly as `double` values, but this is a bad habit to be taking to write loops with floating-point indices this way. Floating-point needs more care than this if you do not want to see strange results. See for instance http://www.mc.edu/campus/users/travis/syllabi/381/patriot.htm

Comment: @Blindy For this precise program, yes he will. For a slightly different program, he wouldn't.

Comment: I want to calculate the area and outline of a circle, the diameter is the parameter, it starts with 1 and ends with 10, it should be incremented by 0.25

Comment: You misunderstand the nature of the floating point problem.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

To prevent being bitten by artifacts of floating point arithmetic, you might want to use an integer loop variable and derive the floating point value you need inside your loop:

```
for (int n = 0; n <= 40; n++) {
    double i = 0.25 * n;
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 28):

You can use `i += 0.25` instead.

Comment: came looking for this!!

Answer (score 11):

James's answer caught the most obvious error. But there is a subtler (and IMO more instructive) issue, in that floating point values should not be compared for (un)equality.

That loop is prone to problems, use just a integer value and compute the double value inside the loop; or, less elegant, give yourself some margin: `for(double i = 0; i < 9.99; i+=0.25)`

Edit: the original comparison happens to work ok, because 0.25=1/4 is a power of 2. In any other case, it might not be exactly representable as a floating point number. An example of the (potential) problem:

```
 for(double i = 0; i < 1.0; i += 0.1) 
     System.out.println(i);
```

prints 11 values:

```
0.0
0.1
0.2
0.30000000000000004
0.4
0.5
0.6
0.7
0.7999999999999999
0.8999999999999999
0.9999999999999999
```

Comment: The original question has `i < 10.0`. Can you explain again how the standard speech about floating-point equality applies here? (as a note, when your floating-point computations are exact it is perfectly safe to use equality).

Comment: 'when your floating-point computations are exact' is a tricky sentence. Because you must be sure that your decimal numbers admit an exact representation in Java's floating number format (0.25 happens to admit it, 0.2 or 0.1 don't) I added an example.

Comment: I am trying to understand how adding 0.01 helps. If the computations are not exact, the floating-point result is as likely to be below the real result as above it, so your "fix" may cause one additional iteration in a loop that already has too many iterations compared to the programmer's intent.

Comment: @Pascal: you're right! I had corrected it, though. Anyway, that's bad practice also.

Answer (score 3):

```
for(double i = 0; i < 10.0; i+=0.25) {
//...
}
```

The added = indicates a shortcut for i = i + 0.25;

Answer (score 2):

In

```
for (double i = 0f; i < 10.0f; i +=0.25f) {
 System.out.println(i);
```

f indicates `float`

The added `=` indicates a shortcut for i = i + 0.25;

Answer (score 0):

For integer. 
We can use : `for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i += 2)`

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i += 2) {
            if (a[i] == a[i + 1]) {
                continue;
            }
            num = a[i];
        }
```

Same way we can do for other data types also.

Answer (score 0):

```
private int getExponentNumber(double value){
    String[] arr;
    String strValue = String.valueOf(value);
    if (strValue.contains("E")){
        arr = strValue.split("E");
        return Math.abs(Integer.parseInt(arr[1]));
    }
    else if (strValue.contains(".")){
        arr = strValue.split("\\.");
        return arr[1].length();
    }
    return 0;
}
private int getMinExponent(int start, int stop, int step){
    int minExponent = Math.max(Math.abs(start), Math.abs(stop));
    minExponent = Math.max(minExponent, Math.abs(step));
    return minExponent;
}

    double start = 0;
    double stop = 1.362;
    double step = 2E-2;
    int startExp = getExponentNumber(start);
    int stopExp = getExponentNumber(stop);
    int stepExp = getExponentNumber(step);
    int min = getMinExponent(startExp, stopExp, stepExp);
    start *= Math.pow(10, min);
    stop *= Math.pow(10, min);
    step *= Math.pow(10, min);

   for(int i = (int)start; i <= (int)stop; i += (int)step)
        System.out.println(i/Math.pow(10, min));
```