# Basic Java - validating for interval decimals

Tags: java, validation

I am struggling with this.  I know how to write the code to determine if a number is between 1.0 and 10.0. Assume that the noOfJudges is a valid input (between 3 and 9)

```
for(noOfJudges = 0; noOfJudges < scores.length; noOfJudges++) {  
  scores[noOfJudges]=console.nextDouble();
  while((scores[noOfJudges] < 1.0)||(scores[noOfJudges] > 10.0)) {
    System.out.print("Please reenter the score (must be between 1.0 and 10.0, in .5 increments): ");
    scores[noOfJudges] = console.nextDouble();
    System.out.println();
  }
  System.out.println();
```

A valid input for the variable would be between 1.0 and 10.0, in 0.5 increments i.e. 4.2 is not a valid input, but 4.5 is. Not sure how to proceed here...

Comment: What about `4.55` and `4.45`, are they valid?

Comment: no  1.0, 1.5,2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5...9.0, 9.5 & 10.0  are the valid inputs

Answer (score 2):

Multiply the input by 2 and check if it's between 2.0 and 20.0, then truncate the decimal places by casting it to an int and check if the truncated value equals the original value (`d == (double)(int)d`), or alternatively round the input and see if it equals the original input (`d == Math.round(d)`)

Answer (score 0):

use something like this

```
   for(double i = 1; i < 10.0; i+=0.5) {
//...
}
```

see the link [for-loop, increment by double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971434/for-loop-increment-by-double) how you can usr integer loop to prevent being bitten by artifacts of floating point arithmetic

Comment: This works only by accident, since 0.5 can be represented *exactly* in floating point.  Try this with 0.1, and round-off errors may hurt you.