# Changing `double` output inside for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, counter

I want to start off saying that I'm new at this. I'm trying to make a for loop that will Show me the different 40 yard dash times converted into MPH. The  problem is output that's being shown:

```
5.96 40 Time is 13.727882855399633 Miles Per Hour 
6.96 40 Time is 11.755485893416928 Miles Per Hour 
7.96 40 Time is 10.27866605756053 Miles Per Hour
```

I want it to show as 5.96, 5.97, 5.98, etc instead of 5.96 and 6.96.

Does anyone understand what I'm trying to do as well as to fix this problem I'm having?

```
public class FortyToMPH {

    public static void main (String args []) {
        double yards, foot, FeetInMiles, SecondsPerHour,FeetLength; 
        double FortyTime, Minutes, SecondsPerMile, MPH; 
        int counter;


        counter = 0;

        for(FortyTime = 4.96; FortyTime <= 7.99; FortyTime++) {  
        yards = 40; // length in yards
        foot = yards * 3; // convert to feet
        System.out.println();

        FeetInMiles = 5280; // The number of feet in a Mile
        SecondsPerHour = 3600;

        FeetLength = FeetInMiles / foot; // You divide the Feet in Miles by the feet conversion of 40 yards
        System.out.println();

        SecondsPerMile = FeetLength * FortyTime;
        MPH = SecondsPerHour / SecondsPerMile;
        System.out.println(FortyTime + " 40 Time is " + MPH + " Miles Per Hour ");

        counter++;
        // every 10th line, print a blank line
        if(counter == 10) {
            System.out.println();
            counter = 0; // reset the line counter


        }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you simply add `0.01` to `FortyTime` instead of `++`?

Comment: Also, please pay a big attention to [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) and change your variable's names.

Comment: perhaps this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971434/for-loop-increment-by-double can help

Comment: The title of this question is not very descriptive of your problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I modified the code you gave to print doubles as a two decimal place numbers (see format %.2f) produced in the loop while (the step for the loop is defined in DELTA variable).

```
public class FortyToMPH 
{ 
    public static void main (String args []) 
    {
        double yards, foot, feetLength; 
        double fortyTime = 4.96, minutes, secondsPerMile, mph; 
        int    counter = 0;
        /**
         * Constants.
         */    
        final double FEET_IN_MILES    = 5280;
        final double SECONDS_PER_HOUR = 3600;
        final double DELTA   = 0.01; 
        final double END     = 7.99;

        while (fortyTime <= END)
        {
            yards = 40; // length in yards
            foot  = yards * 3; // convert to feet

            feetLength = FEET_IN_MILES / foot; // You divide the Feet in Miles by the feet conversion of 40 yards

            secondsPerMile = feetLength * fortyTime;
            mph = SECONDS_PER_HOUR / secondsPerMile;
            System.out.format("%.2f 40 Time is %.2f Miles Per Hour%n", fortyTime, mph);

            counter++;
            // every 10th line, print a blank line
            if(counter == 10) {
                System.out.println();
                counter = 0; // reset the line counter 
            }

            fortyTime += DELTA;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I haven't learned about DELTA and while yet. What's the difference between double and final double ?

Comment: This DELTA is a constant. This is perfectly legal to write without final. The final means, that the value of the variable cannot change once assigned. Constants should have uppercase naming see [Java naming convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367). :)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're using the `++` operator in your for loop definition:

```
for(FortyTime = 4.96; FortyTime <= 7.99; FortyTime++) {
```

Change the for loop to a while loop that includes a line incrementing `FortyTime` by 0.01 each loop:

```
while(FortyTime <= 7.99) { 
    FortyTime += 0.01;
    // execute the rest of your code here
}
```

MarounMaroun rightfully pointed out that using a double as a loop counter runs the risk of nasty floating-point arithmetic errors, so I've changed the for loop to a while loop.

The `++` operator means "reassign the value of x as x + 1." It'll only give you increments (or decrements, with `--`) of 1.

Note that this is going to print out hundreds of lines before it completes.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Hm, I'm scratching my head here - enlighten me? Are there times when adding a hundredth to any number with only two digits of precision is going to result in rounding errors?

Comment: Yes, try to print values of this loop: `for(double i = 0; i < 1.0; i += 0.1)`.

Comment: Or this: `for(double i = 0; i < 1.0; i += 0.01)`

Comment: @MarounMaroun I've changed it now - this shouldn't run into the same issues.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to use `int` in your loop and perform all calculations of `double`s inside the loop to prevent problems with floating point arithmetic:

```
for(int i = 0; i < something; i++) {
    double fortyTime = 4.96 + i;
   //...
}
```

Also please pay attention to [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) and rename your variables.

To demonstrate problems of floating point arithmetic, try this loop:

```
for(double i = 0; i < 1.0; i += 0.1) 
    System.out.println(i);
```

This will print

```
0.0
0.1
0.2
0.30000000000000004
0.4
0.5
0.6
0.7
0.7999999999999999
0.8999999999999999
0.9999999999999999
```

And you don't want output like this in your program.

Answer (score 0):

just change the for loop like this:

```
for(FortyTime = 4.96; FortyTime <= 7.99; FortyTime=FortyTime+.01)
```

and print it like

```
System.out.println((float)FortyTime + " 40 Time is " + MPH + " Miles Per Hour ");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make two changes:

```
for(FortyTime = 4.96; FortyTime <= 7.99; FortyTime=FortyTime+0.01)
```

So that the FortyTime is incremented by 0.01 and not 1 and

```
System.out.printf("%.2f 40 Time is %f Miles Per Hour ", FortyTime, MPH);
```

So that it prints in correct precision.